# Displaying selectInput in sidebar based on tabsetPanel selection in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to generate a list in a selectInput, dynamically. I have a sidebarPanel in which I have declared a tabsetPanel. Each tabsetPanel will have different outputs, all of which I want to display in the sidebar. So the output of the first tab would be a selectInput or perhaps 2 selectInputs, while the same would go for the second tab.

Here is my sidebarPanel code in ui.R

```
## ui.R
sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("aZ", uiOutput("aToZPlayerList")),
              tabPanel("byTeam", uiOutput("byTeamPlayerList"))
        ),
  ),.......
```

In server.R, I have written the following:

```
## server.R
output$aToZPlayerList <- renderUI({
        selectInput("alphabet", "Players A-Z", choices=aToZ, selected=0)
        htmlOutput("List")
  })

  output$byTeamPlayerList <- renderUI({
        selectInput("team", "Teams", choices=teamList, selected=0)
        htmlOutput("List")
  })
```

But this does not work, as nothing is rendered in the sidebarPanel. I feel like I'm missing something, but as I'm quite new to this, I still haven't figured it out.

I haven't been able to find an answer on here or elsewhere as of yet. Any help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have two widgets under one `uiOutput`, i would recommend to  separate it:

```
## ui.R
sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("aZ", uiOutput("aToZPlayerList"), htmlOutput("List")),...

## server.R
output$aToZPlayerList <- renderUI({
        selectInput("alphabet", "Players A-Z", choices=aToZ, selected=0)
})...
```

and it will work.

**[FULL EXAMPLE]**

```
library(shiny)
fruits <- c("banana","raccoon","duck","grapefruit")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  # Application title
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input
  sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("aZ", uiOutput("aToZPlayerList"), htmlOutput("List")),
      tabPanel("byTeam", uiOutput("byTeamPlayerList"))
    )),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$aToZPlayerList <- renderUI({
    selectInput("alphabet", "Players A-Z", choices=c("A","B","C"), selected="A")
   })

  output$List <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste(fruits))
  })

  output$byTeamPlayerList <- renderUI({
    selectInput("team", "Teams", choices=c("A","B","C"), selected="B")})
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll test that out in a little while and if it works, shall accept your answer. It makes sense what you're saying anyway. Cheers!

Comment: I tested this and your suggestion does not work unfortunately. Any other ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: it is actually working well, have a look at the edit i have posted with full example

Comment: Yes, working now actually. I had missed one line, the output$List bit. Thanks again.